# How to create a resource for each combination of values using for_each loop in Terraform

Tags: terraform, monitoring, newrelic

I have the following variable:

```
locals {
  servers = [
    {
      "Environment": "UAT",
      "ServerName": "WebServer01",
      "Disks": [
        "C:",
        "D:"
      ],
    },
    {
      "Environment": "UAT",
      "ServerName": "WebServer02",
      "Disks": [
        "C:",
        "D:"
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

Using a for_each loop, how can I create multiple resources based on a combination of ServerName and each Disk so I end up with 4 resources?

```
WebServer01 C: 
WebServer01 D: 
WebServer02 C: 
WebServer02 D:
```

I've started with the following to no avail.

```
resource "newrelic_alert_policy" "foo" {
  name = "foo"
}

resource "newrelic_nrql_alert_condition" "foo" {
  for_each = { for idx,val in var.servers : idx => val }
  policy_id                      = newrelic_alert_policy.foo.id
  type                           = "static"
  name                           = "foo"
  description                    = "Alert when transactions are taking too long"

  nrql {
    query = "SELECT average(host.disk.usedPercent) as 'Storage Usage' FROM Metric WHERE entity.name = '${each.value.ServerName}' and host.device = '${each.value.Disks}'"
  }

  critical {
    operator              = "above"
    threshold             = 90
    threshold_duration    = 600
    threshold_occurrences = "ALL"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the idea is to create one alert per disk on a server then you could use `flattened` intermediate `local` variable to use in the resources' `for_each` construct.

```
  locals {

  # This is a flattened projection of var.servers. It will contain one entry for each server and disk
  # { server_name = "WbeServer01"  , server_disk="C:" }
  # { server_name = "WbeServer01"  , server_disk="D:" }
    servers_and_disks = flatten([
      for x, server in var.servers : [
        for y, disk in server.Disks : {      
         id = "${server.ServerName}${disk}" 
         server_name = server.ServerName,
         server_disk = disk
        }
      ]
    ])
  }

  resource "newrelic_alert_policy" "foo" {
     name = "foo"
  }

  resource "newrelic_nrql_alert_condition" "foo" {   
    for_each = { for disk in local.servers_and_disks : disk.id => disk }   
    policy_id                      = newrelic_alert_policy.foo.id
    type                           = "static"
    name                           = "foo"
    description                    = "Alert when transactions are taking too long"

    nrql {
      query = "SELECT average(host.disk.usedPercent) as 'Storage Usage' FROM Metric WHERE entity.name = '${each.value.server_name}' and host.device = '${each.value.server_disk}'"
    }

    critical {
      operator              = "above"
      threshold             = 90
      threshold_duration    = 600
      threshold_occurrences = "ALL"
    }

}
```

Comment: After attempting the above. I'm seeing the following error after "terraform apply": 

` Error: Invalid operand

  on ..\..\modules\newrelic\main.tf line 96, in locals:
   96:          id = server.ServerName + disk

 Unsuitable value for right operand: a number is required.`

Comment: Updated the line. Try to concatenate the string this way, however, that value is not really needed. -> "${server.ServerName}${disk}"